# getChar to a char variable for encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I have some basic code here to encrypt a text file. I want to increment each character in the text file by one, possibly something different in the future. But I can't figure out how to set the array "arr" to a char value for incrementing. Any ideas would be helpful!

```
import java.io.*;

public class EncryptionMain {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    File file = new File("c:\\Visual Basic Sign in\\password.txt");
    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String text = null;

        // repeat until all lines is read
        while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            contents.append(text)
                    .append(System.getProperty(
                            "line.separator"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    int first = 0, second = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++)
    {
    char[] arr = new char[7];
    contents.getChars(first, second, arr, 0); // get chars 0,1 to get 1st char
    char ch = arr.toChar();
        if (ch >= 'A' && ch < 'Z') ch++; 
        else if (ch == 'Z') ch = 'A'; 
        else if (ch >= 'a' && ch < 'z') ch++; 
        else if (ch == 'z') ch = 'z'; 

    System.out.println(arr);
    first++;
    second++;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to do encryption, the first thing to do is _not_ to read your file as text, but using byte arrays!

Comment: so...what is the question?

Comment: How do you set the .getChars output to a Char variable?

Answer (score 2):

You need the array access operator `[]` to get and set array elements.  To get...

```
char ch = arr[i];
```

and later to assign it back to the array...

```
arr[i] = ch;
```

Also I don't think you want to map `'z'` to itself.  Change

```
else if (ch == 'z') ch = 'z';
```

to

```
else if (ch == 'z') ch = 'a';
```

Comment: Okay we are getting some where, but when I do that this is my output:
p
q
a

s

s

w

the text file reads, "passw"

Comment: For some reason it just stops printing the encrypted letters.
Desired output: p q a b a b w x
Actual output: p q a a w

Comment: I think it may be because I am using the getChars function wrong.

contents.getChars(first, second, arr, 0);